# Can we use clear() to remove like this?

Tags: python-3.x

I know it's a list method.
list.clear()
but i have created a code:

[err_].clear()

where err_=5  and  I used [] to make it list

then printed it print([err_])

i thought it will cause erorr or empty it
but it executed **[5]**

Answer (score 0):

No, because `.clear()` only removes all elements from the list itself and doesn't do anything to any of the elements.